# Two ExtJS Stores have to load before executing a piece of code

Tags: javascript, extjs3

I have 2 stores, one contains permissions and the other contains data to be displayed in the Grid. But there is a piece of code in my file that has to be executed only after these 2 stores are loaded. Currently in my code with out this condition check there is no guarantee that the stores are loaded before the critical piece of code is executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just listen both stores `load` event?
When you load a store, you flip its flag. When both flags are switched, you call your critical code.

```
{

   firstLoaded: false,
   secondLoaded: false,

   initComponent: function(){
      ...
      firstStore.on('load', function(){ this.firstLoaded=true; this.check(); }, this);
      secondStore.on('load', function(){ this.secondLoaded=true; this.check(); }, this);
      ...
   },

   check: function(){
      if (this.firstLoaded && this.secondLoaded) {
         this.initializeLSEngine();
      }
   },

   initializeLSEngine: function(){
      ...
   }

}
```

Eventually add `{single:true}` to both `.on` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using Extjs, I guess you will have to make use of the callback method.

ExtJs store comes with load callback method. You can load one store first, once it is loaded, then start another store's loading, finally you will be able to know there two stores are both loaded.

Comment: I need the critical code to be called which happens to be a afterrender function only after the 2 stores are loaded

Comment: Then maybe you can place your code into afterrender, once it is all rendered, start loading the store, then other store

Comment: You got it wrong: I want the 2 stores to be loaded first and then the code in the afterrender to be executed. following is the code:
afterrender: function(viewPort)
{
initializeLSEngine();
}

In the above code I want the 2 stores to be executed before the initializeLSEngine is called

Comment: There is not much you can control which one finish first, cause it is event driven. What you really want probably is knowing all the things are ready then call initializeLSEngine(), so it does not matter where do u call initializeLSEngine(). Just my personal opinion. Feel free to use global flag and setTimeout if you like.